# Silverlight ComboBox doesn't bind

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, combobox

When I edit my `Silverlight` DataForm, 
the binding on my `ComboBox` get's lost.

Different I have already taken but failed

Programatically bind my `Combobox` on code behind.

1. `comboBox1.SelectedItem = SelectedItem.ItemStatus;`

   - I tried putting this code both on ContentLoaded and in SelectionChanged but NONE worked

NOTE:
These 3 comboboxes are cascading comboboxes.

Please Help.

Comment: Different I have already taken but failed - What does it means?

Comment: Try using combobox1.SelectedValue instead of combobox1.SelectedItem